# Angular.js Template Function Not Running

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a client side clock that ticks in Angular.js. However, nothing is showing up. For conventions, I wanted the clock to be a service injected into the controller.

html:

```
 <small>Current time is: {{ clientClock.now() | date: 'mediumTime' }} </small>
```

service:

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('clockTicker', function($interval) {
    $interval(function(){ }, 1000);
    return {
            clientClock: function() { return Date; }
    }
});
```

controller:

```
$scope.clientClock = clockTicker.clientClock;
```

Comment: since your clientClock is a function in the factory, try $scope.clientClock = clockTicker.clientClock();  note the parentheses at the end

Comment: was on to the solution and created a fiddler. A bit late though http://jsfiddle.net/4vXSt/

Comment: @Chris Preston - why not submit your solution as an answer?

Comment: @BradWerth - good idea, so this question can be closed. Just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work is because ClientClock inside the factory is a function, therefore it has to be called like this:

```
$scope.clientClock = clockTicker.clientClock();
```

note the parentheses at the end.